# Unable to determine datatype of table column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to be able to determine the datatype of a column in a table.  The database is Oracle 11.

My query is as follows:

```
"select t.data_type from user_tab_columns t where t.TABLE_NAME = '" + table.upper() + "' and t.COLUMN_NAME = '" + column.upper() + "'"
```

But for some reason I am not finding the table_name listed in user_tabl_columns.

I see the table with this command:

```
desc hr.t2
```

But this command finds nothing:

```
select unique table_name from user_tab_columns where table_name='hr.t2';
```

I don't see it listed when I do the following either:

```
select unique table_name from from user_tab_columns;
```

I'm also not seeing it when I do the following:

```
select unique table_name from all_tab_columns;
```

Comment: you'll never find anything with where table_name='hr.t2'; The schema is separate from the object name, and they're generally not lowercase, but instead uppercase. Also, are you logged in as HR? If not, use ALL_ views vs USER_ views

Comment: I had used this URL to generate some random data for testing.  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/06/getting-started-with-oracle-generating-test-data/  It creates a table called 'hr.t2'.  Neither that nor t2 shows up in the user_tab_columns.  I dropped that table and renamed it to HR.  Now it works OK.

Comment: Brent does SQL Server, we're talking Oracle here, right? Show us in the question your connection properties and the exact ddl used to create the table from that script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle object names are typically in uppercase unless they're created surrounded by double quotes (e.g., `hr."t2"`). That's not the case here, since you can refer to the object without double quotes using `desc`. Since the object is referred to as `hr.t2` this means that the owner/schema is `HR` and the object name is `T2`. To find out the data type of a column in `T2`, one would use:

```
SELECT data_type FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE owner = 'HR'
   AND table_name = 'T2'
   AND column_name = '<whatever the column name is>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect to HR, and then Query

```
select table_name 
  from user_tables 
 where table_name='T2';
```

If you see your table here, it means it exists, then query for columns of it as below :

```
select column_name 
  from user_tab_columns 
 where table_name='T2'; -- where "table name" should be  in upper case letters
```

If you can not see that table and you're sure there is a table called T2, then 
you may connect to SYS or SYSTEM schemas, and query as below :

```
select table_name 
  from dba_tables 
 where table_name='T2';
```

Answer (score 1):

When the linked article uses `CREATE TABLE HR.T2`, this creates a table named `T2` in the `HR` schema, not a table named `"HR.T2"`. You would need to look for it in `HR`:

```
select data_type from all_tab_columns
where  owner = 'HR'
and    table_name = 'T2'
```

However, since the `ALL_` views show you only what you have access to via ownership or grants, it's possible that you still won't be able to see it. Has `HR` given you permission to query it? The following shows what `HR` has granted to your user:

```
select * from user_tab_privs_recd
where  grantor = 'HR';
```

Or, connect as `HR` and query the privileges that have have been granted to other users:

```
select * from user_tab_privs_made;
```

Or, if you have been granted access to the DBA views:

```
select * from dba_tab_privs p
where  p.grantor = 'HR';
```

If this is just a demo, then it would be simplest to create the test tables in the same account that your application is connecting to (though this is not advisable in a real system for security reasons). This could be `HR` or some other schema.